# I am trying to POST xml data to a server side php file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have tried a lot of methods but I am still getting an empty array on server side.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/test.php", APP_WEBSITE_URL];    
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[requestObj setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];             
[requestObj setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSInteger tmpCount = [strawPollDetailItem.selectionsArray count];

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SUBMITTED>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
for (int i=0; i<tmpCount; i++) {

    NSInteger selectedID = [strawPollDetailItem.selectionsArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<OPTIONID>%@</OPTIONID>", selectedID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</SUBMITTED>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestObj setHTTPBody:postBody];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestObj delegate:self];
```

Comment: Why don't you try doing some work for yourself instead of taking the answer [someone else gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394933/i-am-try-to-post-the-xml-data-to-server-side-php-file) and reposting it asking someone to do the next piece of your work. Take time to learn things. We are here to HELP you, NOT to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"weblink"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
    [serviceRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    //[serviceRequest setValue:txtTitle.text forHTTPHeaderField:@"title"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [serviceRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[xmlString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    NSURLResponse * serviceResponse;
    NSError * serviceError;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: In php file which variable name should use to get the xml String?